# When iOS says "there are items are that could not be synced" Where in iTunes can I see more information?

Tags: iphone, itunes, data-synchronization

When you get a sync error (somewhat notorious since it's not documented where in iTunes to look for these sync errors) - the iPhone tells you to look in iTunes to see what it was that couldn't be synced.

Interestingly enough *iTunes doesn't actually tell you what it was* that couldn't be synced.

[image]

My question is: **Where precisely in iTunes can I see this more information?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out it is available in iTunes - but not in an obvious place like a dialog that collects all the errors for you to review in a dashboard.

To identify this specific error - here is how I find the problems with my sync:

1. Open iTunes:
2. Select Library
3. Select 'Movies' or 'Music'
4. Go to the View menu and select View As -> List
5. Look at the list of items - and scroll down to the bottom.
6. Observe that the items down the bottom have an exclamation mark next to them.
7. Right click the Item and select Delete.

Alternatively, you could stop syncing that class of content as well if you wanted to search for the files on the computer rather than delete the record of library items that are now unable to sync.

Answer (score 3):

I struggled with this, too. After following several dead ends (from Google searches, e.g., suggesting deleting photo caches, which had no effect on the warning messages for me), and not knowing of @hawkeye's useful information, I noticed that there was a small warning symbol (triangle with an exclamation mark in it) in iTunes, between my device's name and the device eject symbol, at the top of the device panel on the left. When I clicked on the warning symbol, a message popped up describing what the problem was; see the image. (In my case, I didn't have enough free space to replace a particularly large app.)  Apple sure could make this more obvious!

By the way, you can get an unsynced item warning on the device when there isn't a problem, due to stale data in iTunes. You can eliminate the device warning by resetting dialog warnings and the iTunes Store cache in the *Advanced* section of iTunes preferences; there are two buttons there you can push. This solved a mysterious sync warning problem for me in the past.

[image: iTunes sync warning info display]